# How to rename files in folders to foldername using batch file

Tags: file, batch-file, rename, move, directory

Could any of you help me with a problem I have with a lot of files with the same name, placed in sperate folders.
The folders are named with numbers, but the files inside are named index.XXXX - where XXXX could be .jpg or .html or .pdf.
I would like to make a 'program' that can rename all the 'index' files to the same name as the folder they are placed in.
The folders are named with 6 digit numbers - all different.
After this hopefully has been done, then I would like to move all the renamed files to a new single folder, so it will be easier for me to see the whole content.
Looking forward to reading your answers.

Comment: It is operating system specific. Different on POSIX systems and on Windows one.

Answer (score 9):

```
@Echo OFF

FOR /D /R %%# in (*) DO (
    PUSHD "%%#"
    FOR %%@ in ("index*") DO (
        Echo Ren: ".\%%~n#\%%@" "%%~n#%%~x@"
        Ren "%%@" "%%~n#%%~x@"
    )
    POPD
)

Pause&Exit
```

**Tested folder structure:**

```
C:\Users\Administrador\Desktop\Nueva carpeta (3)\123321
C:\Users\Administrador\Desktop\Nueva carpeta (3)\123321\Index.txt

C:\Users\Administrador\Desktop\Nueva carpeta (3)\123456
C:\Users\Administrador\Desktop\Nueva carpeta (3)\123456\Index.php

C:\Users\Administrador\Desktop\Nueva carpeta (3)\123456\000000
C:\Users\Administrador\Desktop\Nueva carpeta (3)\123456\000000\Index.css

C:\Users\Administrador\Desktop\Nueva carpeta (3)\654321
C:\Users\Administrador\Desktop\Nueva carpeta (3)\654321\Index.html

C:\Users\Administrador\Desktop\Nueva carpeta (3)\654321\666999
C:\Users\Administrador\Desktop\Nueva carpeta (3)\654321\666999\Index.jpg
```

**Output:**

```
Ren: ".\123321\Index.txt"      "123321.txt"
Ren: ".\123456\Index.php"      "123456.php"
Ren: ".\654321\Index.html"     "654321.html"
Ren: ".\000000\Index.css"      "000000.css"
Ren: ".\666999\Index.jpg"      "666999.jpg"
```

Comment: Of course add a **Move "%%~n#%%~x@*" "C:\destination\"** after the **Ren "%%@" "%%~n#%%~x@** line, ensure to write the last backslash in the destination apth: C:\Path\ (GOOD) C:\Path (BAD)

Comment: I did the trick with Move... but it didn't Work due to the other commands I did earlier. Is there a command that will only move the renamed files?

Answer (score 7):

If you want a GUI to do all the above, Use [Bulk File Rename](http://www.bulkrenameutility.co.uk/Download.php).

Open it up, Browse to your folder. Now check the **Sub Folders** option in the **Selections** tab. All your files under the folders will be listed. Select the files in the browser.

In the **File** tab switch the first option from **Keep** to **Remove**. Then go to the **Append Folder Name** tab and set option **Prefix** for property **Name**. Click on Rename to complete.

The advantage with this is that it shows you a preview of what your files will be renamed to.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with Brandon that the Bulk File Rename (http://www.bulkrenameutility.co.uk/) is a great way to rename/suffix the files with their directory names under Windows.

To copy all the renamed files to a common directory, use Windows Explorer to do a search for all the filenames with a with a wildcard (e.g. readme*.txt).  Then select all the found files, select copy, navigate to the target directory, and paste.

Answer (score 0):

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL enabledelayedexpansion
SET startfrom=c:\sourcedir
SET destdir=c:\destdir
FOR /f "delims=" %%i IN ('dir /s /b "%startfrom%\index.*"') DO (
 FOR %%e IN (jpg html pdf) DO IF /i .%%e==%%~xi (
  FOR %%d IN ("%%~dpi.") DO (
   SET "var=%%~nxd"
   IF "!var:~6!"=="" (
    SET "var="
    SET /a var=1%%~nxd 2>NUL
    IF DEFINED var IF !var! geq 1000000 IF !var! leq 1999999 (
     ECHO MOVE "%%i" "%destdir%\%%~nxd%%~xi"
    )
   )
  )
 )
)
```

- Get the 'index.*' files
- filter on extensions specified
- find the immediate directory name
- check that it is not longer than 6 characters
- attempt to `set` a variable to 1000000..1999999 if 6-digit name
- if successful `ECHO` the move command (remove ECHO keyword to perform move)

Annotated test structure:

```
c:\sourcedir\index.pdf                not 6-digit dir
c:\sourcedir\000000\index.jpg
c:\sourcedir\000009\index.css         extension not specified
c:\sourcedir\000009\index.html
c:\sourcedir\000009\index.jpg
c:\sourcedir\000009\index.pdf
c:\sourcedir\000009\index.txt         extension not specified
c:\sourcedir\010+39\index.txt         not 6-digit dir
c:\sourcedir\12345\index.jpg          not 6-digit dir
c:\sourcedir\1234567\index.jpg        not 6-digit dir
c:\sourcedir\123x56\index.jpg
c:\sourcedir\50000-0000\index.jpg     not 6-digit dir
c:\sourcedir\5000000000\index.jpg     not 6-digit dir
c:\sourcedir\999-99\index.jpg         not 6-digit dir
c:\sourcedir\999999\index.jpg
c:\sourcedir\a\index.jpg              not 6-digit dir
c:\sourcedir\yellow\index.jpg         not 6-digit dir
```

Results:

```
MOVE "c:\sourcedir\000000\index.jpg" "c:\destdir\000000.jpg"
MOVE "c:\sourcedir\000009\index.html" "c:\destdir\000009.html"
MOVE "c:\sourcedir\000009\index.jpg" "c:\destdir\000009.jpg"
MOVE "c:\sourcedir\000009\index.pdf" "c:\destdir\000009.pdf"
MOVE "c:\sourcedir\999999\index.jpg" "c:\destdir\999999.jpg"
```

Comment: My interpretation is that all index.* files are to be processed.  Fiberflux will have to confirm.

Comment: I tried this solution - but nothing happened. Maybe due to the fact that a few of the folders actually was 7 digits. Elektro Hacker's solution worked fine, but didn't move the files.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone finding the moving to parent Folder, you can use this for your batch series. Put it in the parent folder where you want your subfolder files to be moved to.

```
@Echo OFF
FOR /D /R %%# in (*) DO (
    PUSHD "%%#"
    FOR %%@ in (*) DO (
        Echo Moving: "%%~n#\%%@" "%%~n#\"   
        Echo "\%%#"\"%%@" 
        move "%%#"\"%%@" C:\Docs
    )
    POPD
)

Pause&Exit
```

C Docs to be change to your parent folder

Cheers,

Uriel John