# Can I batch rename files with folder name and sequence number?

Tags: windows, batch-file, command

I can rename the files in all the directories and sub directories using the following script

```
@Echo OFF

FOR /D /R %%# in (*) DO (
    PUSHD "%%#"
    FOR %%@ in ("index*") DO (
        Echo Ren: ".\%%~n#\%%@" "%%~n#%%~x@"
        Ren "%%@" "%%~n#%%~x@"
    )
    POPD
)

Pause&ExiT
```

is there a way to modify the script, which worked fine for me in the 2nd answer to rename files in a sequence when there is multiple files in the directory?

Like, the folder name is `image` and I want the files to be named `image1.jpg` `image2.jpg` (retaining the extension).. Help is much appreciated

Comment: In the future, try to not use html to format your code examples. Markdown is much simpler and preferred http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help

Comment: Do you have some special reason to use # and @ in loop variable names?  They obfuscate the code.

Comment: No I found the code here - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16266930/how-to-rename-files-in-folders-to-foldername-using-batch-file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
@Echo OFF
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
FOR /D /R %%# in (*) DO (
    PUSHD "%%#"
    FOR %%@ in ("index*") DO (
        set /a "inc+=1"
        Echo Ren: ".\%%~n#\%%@" "%%~n#!inc!%%~x@"
        Ren "%%@" "%%~n#!inc!%%~x@"
    )
    POPD
)

Pause&Exit
```

Comment: You can accept the answer and people searching in the future will immediately know that it is worth looking at.

Comment: Sorry couldnt put thisngs clearly in comment so I asked another question please find it here, many thanks http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21632266/batch-rename-files-in-the-folder-with-name-of-the-folder-with-sequence-number