# Batch rename files with the folder name and sequence number - Send To Menu

Tags: windows, batch-file, command-line

I have a folder called sales. I have imgxy.jpg, imgab.jpg etc in that folder. When I right click the sales folder and send to rename.bat file (I have already copied the rename.bat file into **c:\documents and settings\username\send To**) I want the files in the sales folder to change to sales1.jpg, sales2.jpg etc. This behaviour should be true for anything I send to this .bat file. The following code was working properly on windows 7 last night. Now I am om windows xp sp3 and it doest work. It is trying to rename files in the folder   ***c:\documents and settings\username***

Please help rename.bat file code below

```
@ECHO OFF
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set foldername=%1
for %%i in (%bar%) do set bar=%%~ni
FOR /D  %%# in (%bar%) DO (
PUSHD "%%#"
FOR %%@ in ("*") DO (
    set /a "inc+=1"
    Echo Ren: ".\%%~n#\%%@" "%%~n#!inc!%%~x@"
    Ren "%%@" "%%~n#!inc!%%~x@"
)
POPD
)
```

Comment: Is this the actual script? Why is there a `foldername` variable that isn't used anywhere after a value is assigned to it? Why is the `bar` variable referenced (in the first `for` loop) before any value is assigned to it? Are `foldername` and `bar` supposed to be the same variable, perhaps?

Comment: Hi the script does other things and for that i have assigned it, for the convenience of posting i have taken the rest of the code off. folder name gives full path to the folder, where bar give the parent folder name only

Comment: I mean, shouldn't the first `for` loop look like this: `for %%i in (%foldername%) do set bar=%%~ni`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Test this - it accepts a folder, not files, but you mentioned folders in your question.

Don't call it `rename.bat` because `rename` is an internal command.

```
@ECHO OFF
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
PUSHD "%~1"
set inc=0
FOR /f "delims=" %%a in ('dir /b /a-d') DO (
    set /a inc+=1
    Echo Ren: "%%a" "%~n1!inc!%%~xa"
    Ren "%%a" "%~n1!inc!%%~xa"
)
POPD
```

Comment: hi thank you, rename was a symbolic name used, i tried the code and it goes through the rename cycle and rename the file by its own file name (Ren: "IMG_105511.JPG" "IMG_1055111.JPG")hence nothing changes, but the above one i have used works on winows 7

Comment: Look again.  The renamed file has an extra 1 at the end which is what you asked for.

Comment: Yes I agree that, but wanted the file name to be name by the name of its folder name. Here all it does is adding a sequence number to the existing file name. Thanks

Comment: That wasn't clear to me.  Try the edited code above.

Comment: Thank you, the code worked like a treat. Thanks again

Comment: Your welcome.  If it works for you then please accept the answer by clicking on the tick next to it.  People searching in the future will know that it is worth trying.