# Append file name with name of the folder and replace `-` and remove spaces

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I have a folder which contains

```
P:\RECORDINGS\2020-04-08 14-09-07 - VIDS - -\VIDS - -.mp4
P:\RECORDINGS\2020-04-08 14-09-07 - VIDS - -\VIDS - -.json
P:\RECORDINGS\2020-04-08 14-09-07 - VIDS - -\VIDS - -.aaf
```

I would like files to be renamed based on the folder that holds them.

```
P:\RECORDINGS\2020-04-08 14-09-07 - VIDS - -\2020-04-08 14-09-07-VIDS.mp4
P:\RECORDINGS\2020-04-08 14-09-07 - VIDS - -\2020-04-08 14-09-07-VIDS.json
P:\RECORDINGS\2020-04-08 14-09-07 - VIDS - -\2020-04-08 14-09-07-VIDS.aaf
```

What I get is the following

```
P:\RECORDINGS\2020-04-08 16-01-12 - TEST - ->(
Echo Ren: ".\2020-04-08 16-01-12 - TEST - -\TEST - -.m4a" "2020-04-08 16-01-12 - TEST - -.m4a"
 Ren "TEST - -.m4a" "2020-04-08 16-01-12 - TEST - -.m4a"
```

I have this code, however, it does not seem to append the name, moreso replace it.

```
@echo on
Setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

FOR /D /R %%# in (*) DO (
    PUSHD "%%#"
    FOR %%@ in ("*") DO (
        Echo Ren: ".\%%~n#\%%@" "%%~n#%%~x@"
        Ren "%%@" "%%~n#%%~x@"
    )
    POPD
)
```

The above code came from: [click here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16266930/how-to-rename-files-in-folders-to-foldername-using-batch-file/16268898#16268898) (The closet I could find)

**Update**

`@echo off
Setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
rem - keeps the first 19 chas of the folder names
for /F "delims=" %%D in ('dir /B /A:D "*"') do (
    set "FOLDER=%%D"
    setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
    ren "!FOLDER!" "!FOLDER:~,19!"
    endlocal
)
for /r %%a in (*.*) do for %%b in ("%%~dpa\.") do echo ren "%%~a" "%%~nxb____%%~xa"`

Okay. So I have cleaned up the folders now. `"%%~nxb____%%~xa"` I need to put here the filename, however, I am not sure how to get the information. I have been looking at `%%f`. However, I am not sure how to add it in the above code. Not I am a little lost.

Comment: Your code makes no attempt at renaming the files whilst replacing characters and is therefore about renaming files by prefixing them with their parent directory names. You've left `echo`ing on and have also `Echo`ed each `Ren`ame before doing so, please [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/61102428/edit) to show us what the output reads

Comment: It's also worth mentioning that your resulting files do not match the description in your question title. Those files would look like this, `2020_04_0814_09_07_TEST__TEST__.mp4`, `2020_04_0814_09_07_TEST__TEST__.json`, and `2020_04_0814_09_07_TEST__TEST__.aaf`.

Comment: Hi, yes exactly, that is why I am trying to fix it. I have been trying to edit this code. But it is not working as of yet the way I want it to.

Comment: So, please edit your question, as already advised, to show us exactly what you're using, what the original files and directories are and what the resultant files and directories are, complete with the output to your console window. You're not the first person on this particular part of this site, who has asked to prefix files with their parent directory names. Have you used the search facility, which questions/code did you find? You've stated that you've tried to edit the code, can you provide us with what you've tried? or are we supposed to guess and therefore not offer the same or similar?

Comment: 1. Why are you using `for /R` although yuo have got a flat directory structure (at least according to your sample data)? 2. Besides a [mcve] of your coding attempts, you should also [edit] your question and clearify how exactly the file names are to be built; as I guess `TEST` is just a placeholder for something else, you are the one to tell us whether or not this part may contain spaces on its own; also what if a current file name does not match the `TEST - -` portion of the parent directory?

Comment: 3. You should avoid using characters like `#` and `@` for `for` meta-variables; though they work, they just make code harder to read, so better use letters as shown in the help text of `for /?`...

Comment: Your edit still does not follow a specific pattern, currently you're trying to copy the directory name, e.g. `2020-04-08 14-09-07 - VIDS - -`, remove all space characters in that, except for one somewhere in the middle, _(which you'd like to replace with two underscores)_, then you want to either remove `VIDS__` from the end of that and prefix it to the file name, which should also have all space characters and hyphens removed, or remove `_` from the end of the parent directory name and replace the entire file's basename with that string. You're trying to run before you can walk, slow down!

Comment: You are right. I can mange the spaces and the `-` / `_` after getting the correct files names first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution:

```
rem - Rename files based on folder name
for /d %%D in (*) do (
  pushd "%%D"
  for /r %%F in (*) do (
    for %%P in ("%%F\..") do (
      ren "%%F" "%%~nxP_%%~nxF"

    )
  )
  popd
)
popd
```